# Playing movies one after the other in iPhone with a seamless transistion

Tags: avfoundation

I am trying to play a few movies, one after the other, in which the transition from onw moive to the next will be seamless to the user. 
I know i can use AVComposition, but this is not good for me as i want the user to choose on run time which movie will be played next.
Using AVQeueuPlayer is no good too since the transition between the movies is noticeable.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: have you been able to make it work. Can you share your knowledge on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to create a table with all the possible movies to be played, when the user selects a cell he makes his choice, save this choice on a variable and set the player to play the chosen file on the playbackdidfinish notification method.

Comment: Hi Marco and thanks for your answer though it does not do the trick. On playbackdidfinish, i am able to play the next movie, but the transition is not seamless.

Comment: Yeah, well, I think a seemless transition is too much to ask for an iOS device. I have a last resource idea, you could try playing with the prepareToPlay method, it reduces latency a little bit.